# Find query not working with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find, fetch, ejs

So I have collected the username and password entered by the users in the `username` and `password` variables respectively.

But when I use this `username` variable inside find query then it is returning an empty document even though there is a record present in the database with the same username.

But when I directly specify the username (in the database) in the query then it returns me the correct result.

**app.js**

```
app.post('/controlPanel',function (req,res) {
    var username=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.password;
    console.log('req body username : '+username);
    console.log('req body password : '+password);

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/registration';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        console.log('username : '+username);
        var cursor = db.collection('admin').find({'username':username});

        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {

            console.log(doc);
            // res.send(doc);
        });

    });

});
```

**adminlogin.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Login </title>
    <style>label,input{
        display:block;
    }</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/controlPanel" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" required />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's the output here? You have several log statements in your code, could you provide an example log?

Comment: Take a look at the examples on [`.find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find) in the documentation and spot the differences.

Comment: `req body username : admin
req body password : admin
username : admin
null` @thwiegan

Comment: If it just wouldn't find a document, it shouldn't even print `null`. Could you print the err object within the `each` function and add the output?

Comment: I've updated my code as  : `var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost/registration';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        console.log('username : '+username);
         db.collection('admin').findOne({'username':username},function (err,doc) {
            if(doc.password==password) {
                console.log('success !!!');
            }
             else
             console.log('Failed !!!');
         });`  now it is working fine thank you for your help sir !!! @thwiegan

Comment: I removed the cursor and each function